# technical problem on python with infinite float

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, floating-point, infinite-loop

I am using Python, and I have a problem, I want to do a program tha can count from 1 to infinite, to know how much is the infinite. 
Here is my code :

```
a=0
for i in range(1, 10e+99):
  a += 1
  print (a)
```

but it says "  'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer  "

whereas 10e+99 is not a float
help me please

Comment: `10e+99` is a `float` literal, so *it is a float*. Why do you think it isn't a `float`? Try `print(type(10e+99))`

Comment: ... also `10e+99` is not infinite either...

Comment: So how can I know how much is the infinite ? 
I have the feeling that nobody really tries to know

Comment: I honestly have no idea what you are asking. There is plenty of basic mathematical work on the concept of infinity. So, there certainly is a lot of people who are really trying to know. In any case, your particular problem here is that `10e+99` is a `float` object, and `range` does not accept `float` objects. You could use `1**100` for an `int` object that represents that value (which again, **is not infinite anyway**).

Comment: Infinite is very big so I think it must be hidden somewhere between 1 and 10e+99 
So I want to print all these numbers and wait for the "infinite" to appear

Comment: @TimothéeTardy, infinite is just that, it has no end in theory. it will only be limited by your hardware

Comment: "Infinite is very big so I think it must be hidden somewhere between 1 and 10e+99" That is simply not a valid inference. In any case, there is a closed-form solution to your question here, The sum of a series of increasing integers starting at 1 and ending at N is `n*(n - 1) // 2`

Comment: ok so I could take this sum n*(n - 1) // 2 and do +1 until infinite, it could work 
Thank you for your help, I know I'm a beginner but now I think I better understand where is infinite

Comment: @TimothéeTardy no. You can keep adding `1` or any integer to another integer and it will never be "infinite" because for any integer, I can always create an integer bigger than it.

Comment: 1st of all infinity is a terms that has no end means if you are some how able to print it i think you have to wait infinity time to end it. 
2nd if you are interested infinity then this link may be helpful.
https://www.stechies.com/python-infinity/

Comment: Thank you infinite is my new favorite thing after cats

Comment: In IEEE-754 32-bit binary floating-point, the largest representable finite number is about 3.4028e38. When converting numerals, such as `1e99` in source code, to this format, any number greater than or equal to 2^128-2^104 (340,282,377,062,143,265,289,209,819,405,393,854,464) will be converted to infinity. Because of this, `10e+99`, which stands for 10•10^99 and hence 10^100, would act like infinity. However, Python implementations more typically use 64-bit binary floating-point, in which the largest representable finite number is 2^1024-2^971, and `10e99` acts as a finite number.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: `1**100` is 1.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: The code in the question executes `a += 1`, not `a += i`. The value of `a` after `n` iterations is `n`, not `n*(n-1)/2`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil yes, that was a typo,  I meant 10**100. And yes, good call about the loop. In which case, the closed form solution is even simpler...

Comment: @EricPostpischil the floating point number information is good, but note, the OP is adding integers, which are arbitrarily sized in Python.

Comment: wait so 1^100 is 1 but 1^100 equals infinity 
So is 1 equal to infinity ?

Comment: I don't think so, but it's mathematically correct

Comment: @TimothéeTardy: No, `1**100` was a mistake. `1**100` is 1 and is not infinity. `10*100` will be bigger than any number you can make the computer count to one at a time, so it will serve as infinity for some purposes.

Comment: at school, they said that infinity +1 = infinity
So if 10^100 is infinity 10^100 +1 = 10^100 
but 1 is not equal to 0 
So 10^100 can't be infinity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem arises because the `range()` function takes an `int`, whereas 10e+99 is indeed a `float`. While 10e+99 is of course not infinity, and therefore you shouldn't expect infinity to pop up anywhere during the execution of your program, if you really wanted to get your for loop to work *as it is* you could simply do

```
a=0
for i in range(1, int(10e+99)):
    a += 1
    print (a)
```

As other users have pointed out, I would however rethink your strategy entirely: using a range-based for loop to "find out" the value of infinity just doesn't work. Infinity is not a number.

Answer (score 1):

1. Per the [Python 2 documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range) and [Python 3 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-range), `range` requires integer arguments.
2. In IEEE-754 32-bit binary floating-point, the largest representable finite number is about 3.4028e38. When converting numerals, such as `1e99` in source code, to this format, any number greater than or equal to 2<sup>128</sup>−2<sup>104</sup> (340,282,377,062,143,265,289,209,819,405,393,854,464) will be converted to infinity, assuming the common round-to-nearest-ties-to-even method is used. Because of this, `10e+99` (which stands for 10•10<sup>99</sup> and hence 10<sup>100</sup>) would act like infinity. However, Python implementations more typically use IEEE-754 64-bit binary floating-point, in which the largest representable finite number is 2<sup>1024</sup>−2<sup>971</sup>, and `10e99` acts as a finite number.<sup>1</sup> Thus, to get infinity, you would need around `1e309`.
3. It is not humanly possible to test whether a loop incrementing by 1 from 1 to `10e99` will produce infinity because the total computing power available to humans is only around 10<sup>30</sup> additions per year (for a loose sense of “around”, some orders of magnitude). This is insufficient to count to the limit of 32-bit floating-point finite numbers, let alone that of the 64-bit floating-point numbers.
4. If the arithmetic were done in a floating-point format, it would never reach infinity even with unlimited computing power because, once the sum reached 2<sup>53</sup> in IEEE-754 64-bit binary, adding 1 would not change the number; 2<sup>53</sup> would be produced in each iteration. This is because IEEE-754 64-bit binary has only 53 bits available for the significand, so 2<sup>53</sup>+1 is not representable. The nearest representable values are 2<sup>53</sup> and 2<sup>53</sup>+2. When arithmetic is performed, the exact real-number result is by default rounded to the nearest representable value, with ties rounded to the number with the even low bit in its significand. When 1 is added to 2<sup>53</sup> the real-number result 2<sup>53</sup>+1 is rounded to 2<sup>53</sup>, and the sum thus stays at 2<sup>53</sup> for all future iterations.

### Footnote

<sup>1</sup> The representable value nearest 10<sup>100</sup> is 10,000,000,000,000,000,159,028,911,097,599,180,468,360,808,563,945,281,389,781,327,557,747,838,772,170,381,060,813,469,985,856,815,104.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you meant your program to go on forever:

```
a = 0
while True:
  a += 1
  print(a)
```

In my head when I see `while True:` I replace it with 'forever'.

Answer (score 0):

With is code you can check you variable is infinity or not.

```
import math

infinity = float('inf')
a = 99999999999999999999999999999999
if a > infinity:
 print('Your number is an infinity number')
else:
 print('Your number is not an infinity number')

#or you can check with math.isinf

print('Your number is Infinity: ',math.isinf(infinity ))

# Also infinity can be both positive and negative
```

Note: infinity is infinity that has no end, whatever your value or number you enter it will always return false.

Comment: This will never work, `a > infinity` will be false for *all values of a* (for built-in types, you can always create a type which returns whatever you want for a comparison)

Comment: yeh I know it will always return false coz infinity is infinity that has no end. it is just a terms, this code is to understand the infinity, that maybe help to him who posted.

Comment: In floating-point systems that include infinity, `a > infinity` is false when `a` is infinity, but `a >= infinity` is true.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what is going to happen if you correct and execute your program:

```
a=0
for i in range(1, 10**100):
  a += 1
  print (a)
```

Suppose you have a super efficient python virtual machine (everyone knows how efficient they are...).

Suppose you have a very efficient implementation of (unbounded) large integers.

Suppose each loop takes a few machine cycles to print those numbers in decimal form (say only 1000 which is well under reality).

Suppose each cycle takes approximately 1.0e-10 s (10GHz) which means having an implementation of print taking advantage of parallelism.

With those irrealistic hypothesis, that's already 10^93 s necessary for the program to complete.

The age of universe is estimated to be less than 10^18 s. Whaouh! It gonna be long.

Now let's compute the energy it's gonna take on a base of 400W computer.
Assuming that all Sun matter (2e30 kg) can be converted into electrical power for your computer (thru E=m c^2), you are going to consume about 2 10^48 equivalent of Sun to perform this computation.

Before you hit return, I kindly ask you: think twice! Save the universe!